# Why is Visual Studio build so slow for small database program?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

Building solutions with Visual Studio 2015 have always been fast (even with complex programs).  But now I'm simply trying to learn database programming and this basic code below takes **over 2 minutes to build**.  It compiles and runs fine, but why so long to build?  Anything I can change in the code to have it build faster?

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient; 

namespace DBtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DatabasePlay\DBtest\DB2.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Open!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Takes about 30 seconds for me the first time, and then rebuilding takes a couple of seconds.

Comment: You likely have a plugin in your visual studio slowing it down, uninstall all of the plugins you have added one by one till it speeds back up.

Comment: Check for the build output. It will tell you what takes a long time.

Comment: Build output just has 3 lines, one saying build started, one with file name, and then third saying 
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Don't think plug-ins are the issue, none of them are new and other projects still build fast.  It's only this one that gives me trouble.

Comment: Do you really mean a clean build process takes that long or hitting F5?

Comment: t3hb0t, I click "build" and then "build solution" (F6).  Worked fine for every other project I've done before.  I even just checked some old projects and they still build fine (few seconds at most).

Comment: UPDATE: so I deleted the database I was connecting to, and recreated it. 
 No idea how that fixed it but it's fast again.  Maybe related to deleting a plug in earlier (even though didn't immediately speed it up)?  Anyway, it's working now.  Thanks for all your comments.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else ever experiences this same problem: if you create a database within visual studio (add > new item > server-based database), the database file will be "looked at" each time you try to build the project.  This isn't an issue at first, but as you add data to the database it will result in builds being very slow.

The problem is fixed by simply putting your database file in another folder, or right clicking the database and "exclude from file" (by default Visual Studio includes the database in the project).